# Problem with Scala matching + scope

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Given the following code:

```
case class ChangeSet(field:String, from:Object, to:Object)

private var changed:List[ChangeSet] = Nil

def change(field:String, from:Object, to:Object) {
  changed.find{ case ChangeSet(field,_,_) => true } match {
    case Some(ChangeSet(field,to,_)) => // do stuff
    case Some(_) => // do stuff
    case _ => // do stuff
  }
}
```

The line giving me trouble is `Some(ChangeSet(field,to,_))`.

It compiles but what seems to be happening is that Scala is filling it in as a placeholder for a wildcard. I base that assumption on the fact that when I do the following `Some(ChangeSet(field,to,to))` I get the error `to is already defined as value`.

What I wanted is to make a ChangeSet object with `to` from the method parameters.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When pattern matching Scala interprets all identifiers starting with lower case as placeholders and fills in values. To tell Scala to use `to` as a constant value from the outer scope you need to surround it with backticks: `` `to` ``. Alternatively, you could change the name of `to` to `To` as Rex Kerr suggested, but I prefer to keep my variables lowercase.

This should work:

```
def change(field:String, from:Object, to:Object) {
  changed.find{ case ChangeSet(`field`,_,_) => true } match {
    case Some(ChangeSet(`field`, `to`, _)) => // do stuff
    case Some(_) => // do stuff
    case _ => // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: The trickiest part with backticks notation is how to get it to show up properly in a StackOverflow answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

It seems there are two confusions here. The first one is the one identified by Rex and Kim. You can read [this section](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#subsec%3akinds-of-patterns-variables) from *Programming in Scala* for more information. It boils down to:

```
x match { case Some(foo) => } // variable pattern, defines and binds variable foo
x match { case Some(Foo) => } // constant pattern, based on val Foo
x match { case Some(`foo`) => } // constant pattern for lowercase val
```

You can also use a guard to constraint the match

```
x match { case Some(foo) if condition => }
```

---

The second confusion is that you want to *"make a ChangeSet object with to from the method parameters"*. If I understand you correctly you are trying to construct an object using the case class syntax:

```
ChangeSet(field, from, to)
```

This does not work on that side of pattern matching. What happens on the *case* side of the pattern match can actually be seen as the **reverse** of the construction of ChangeSet. `match { case ChangeSet(field, from, to) => }` sort of deconstructs your `ChangeSet` object and assigns its parts to the `field`, `from` and `to` vals. This is also true when it's composed like this: `Some(ChangeSet(field, from, to))`, it first deconstructs `Some` and then `ChangeSet`. You can see that working on *value definitions* as it is leveraging the same deconstruction mechanism:

```
scala> val cset = ChangeSet("a", "from", "to")
cset: ChangeSet = ChangeSet(a,from,to)

scala> val Some(ChangeSet(s, o1, o2)) = Some(cset)
s: String = a
o1: java.lang.Object = from
o2: java.lang.Object = to
```

It seems what you want to do is to construct a new object that copies the value of `ChangeSet` but replacing a single field. Case classes supports this with `copy`, continuing with my REPL example:

```
scala> val cset2 = cset.copy(from = o2)
cset2: ChangeSet = ChangeSet(a,to,to)
```

With that in mind, here is another suggestion for `change`:

```
def change(field:String, from:Object, to:Object) {
  changed.find(_.field == field) match {
    case Some(cset) =>
      val csetnew = cset.copy(from = to)
      // do stuff with csetnew
    case None =>
      // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable names in patterns like that. You have to first match it to a new variable and then do an explicit comparison.

```
def change(field:String, from:Object, to:Object) {
  changed.find{ case ChangeSet(f,_,_) => field == f } match {
    case Some(ChangeSet(f,too,_)) if f == field && to == too => // do stuff
    case Some(_) => // do stuff
    case _ => // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite correct: you can use the backticks notation, as shown  in [kassens's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172557/problem-with-scala-matching-scope/6173342#6173342).

Comment: I don't know; since longer than two years ago at least :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a lower-case name in a pattern match, Scala will fill in the value.  If you want to only match if you have that value, you need to use an upper-case name.  Leaving aside the logic of what you're trying to do, and the questionable change in ordering of names, you want:

```
def change(Field: String, from:Object, To: Object) {
  changed.find{
    case ChangeSet(Field,_,_) => true
    case _ => false   // You need this line!  No match is an exception, not false!
  } match {
    case Some(ChangeSet(Field,To,_)) => // do stuff
    case Some(_) => // do stuff
    case _ => // do stuff
  }
}
```